# Windows 8 clean installation stuck at "installing update" any chance to skip this step?

Tags: windows-8, installation

I am installing windows 8 pro from a USB drive. While installation it is set to format my hard drive and create partitions. After that installation it starts properly but it gets stuck when installing updates. I am not connected to internet. It has gone 3 hours installing updates.

My HCL laptop configuration are as below:

RAM : 3GB,
Processor : intel core 2 duo
Hard drive : 160GB

Thanks in advance.

Update :

After 5 hours it shows the error "Windows could not update registry data in the installation".

Comment: Please check whether your USB thumb drive is okay. I recommend using [h2testw](http://www.heise.de/download/h2testw.html) to verify the state of your drive.

Comment: My USB drive is working fine.

Comment: After five hours it throws error :- "Windows could not update registry data in the installation."

Comment: So did you test it or not? You can’t know whether it’s working unless you test it, you know.

Comment: I finally found and issue with my laptop hard drive. It has lots of bad sectors on laptop hard drive.